# Paginaton Can't Select Original

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my webpage, my main problem is with Bootstrap and JQuery working together.

```js
$("ul.pagination li:not(.active) a").on("click",function(){
 $(".pagination li.active").removeClass("active");
 $(this).parent().addClass("active");
 $(".page").hide();
 $("#"+$(this).text().toLowerCase()+"Page").show(); });
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class='pagination'>
  <li class='active'>
    <a href='#'>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>Outside</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>Fort</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, it works fine. Until you attempt to move back to the page that was initially active. I also have the code I use for switching pages in the snipped, does anyone has a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your original selector to

```
$("ul.pagination li a").on("click",function(){
```

Otherwise, you aren't binding a click event.

```js
$("ul.pagination li a").on("click",function(){
 $(".pagination li.active").removeClass("active");
 $(this).parent().addClass("active");
 $(".page").hide();
 $("#"+$(this).text().toLowerCase()+"Page").show(); });
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class='pagination'>
  <li class='active'>
    <a href='#'>Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>Outside</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>Fort</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are attaching the `onclick` event only for the not active elements (excluding the first active). You have to make all elements clickable and check if the clicked element is not active inside your handler:

```
// Add a handler to all elements
$("ul.pagination li a").on("click",function(){
   var clicked = $(this);
   if(!clicked.parent().hasClass("active")) {
      // Do what you want
   }
});
```